# Form Validation on Hashed Passwords

Tags: validation, laravel, hash

I'm utilising [Way's Model Validation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation) methods and have set my password field to `between:8,20`

This model validation plugin works by hooking into the save methods and validating there. However, I am also utilising the following method for hashing the password:

```
/**
 * Dynamically hashes passwords before they enter the database
 * @param string $pass Input Password
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($pass)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);
}
```

With this in mind, I think that as the hashing method generates a set character string, this is causing the `between:8,20` rule to fail.

What could I do to get around this?

Comment: Why limit the password to 20? Let it be up to 60.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the issue, as it wouldn't then catch passwords that are too short.

Comment: Yep - I didnt mean it as a solution to the problem. Just a comment in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the problems with model validation.

You need to remove the mutator, and instead hook into the 'creating' event. This way the password is hashed on saving, after the validation has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I've declared my User::saving event in the boot function of my model, and it doesn't seem to run. Everything gets added to the database but the password isn't hashed. Logging doesn't work within the event either.

Comment: Sorry - should have been the 'creating' event. Answer updated.